# build a collection using java8 streams

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

I have written this code to build a collection of objects concurrently using an Executor.newFixedThreadPool and a ConcurrentLinkedQueue. However, I find this whole thread pool and task submission to it verbose. I wish I could write it more concisely using streams.

```
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRunner> getRunners(final ApiRunnerBuilder builder,
        final int testSize) throws InterruptedException {

    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_OF_CORES);
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRunner> runners = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRunner>();
    for (int i = 0; i < testSize; i++) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            runners.add(builder.build());
        });
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return runners;
}
```

I'm thinking maybe it could be reduced to something like this (new to java and new to streams):

```
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRunner> getRunners(final ApiRunnerBuilder builder,
        final int testSize) throws InterruptedException {

    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRunner> runners = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRunner>();
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRunner> runners = range(testSize).parallelStream(()-> {
            runners.add(builder.build());
        });
    }
    return runners;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRunner> runners =
    Stream.generate(() -> builder.build())
          .parallel()
          .limit(testSize)
          .collect(toCollection(ConcurrentLinkedQueue::new));
```

Comment: For what it's worth: I _very strongly_ suspect that `parallel()` will only slow this code down, not speed it up.

Comment: It’s worth noting that in this example there is no need for a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` as the stream implementation takes care of proper synchronization.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That is probably true, unless ``build()`` is a costly operation.

Comment: @Holger Agreed. ``ConcurrentLinkedQueue`` does not seem to be the right structure to return. A simple ``List<ApiRunner>`` with ``.collect(toList())`` is probably cleaner.

Comment: It works. Performance wise I couldn't tell the difference between executor and parallelStream. Building the collection serially is too slow as the collection is very big and build has lots of I/O. So parallelStream is my preferable impl.

Answer (score 6):

Since you said, you have lots of I/O involved, I don’t recommend using the stream API. The stream API is optimized for CPU bound tasks as it adjusts the number of threads according to the number of CPU cores, but for I/O bound tasks, an even higher number of threads might be preferable as threads blocked waiting for the completion of an I/O operation do not consume CPU resources.

Note that the old API also plays nice with the new lambda expressions:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(DESIRED_CONCURRENCY);
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRunner> runners = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRunner>();
executor.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(testSize, ()->runners.add(builder.build())));
executor.shutdown();
return runners;
```

In real applications you might keep the executor longer than for this task. The method `invokeAll` already waits for the completion of all tasks, so neither shutdown nor waiting for the termination is necessary here. The `shutdown` invocation is only added in this example for cleaning up as in this case you’ve created the executor right inside the method.